# OpenGL 2D polygonal shape drawing and manipulation?

Tags: opengl, 2d, polygon, libgdx

I'm working on a 2D game project where I am expecting users to draw 2D polygons (closed path) such as:

[image: Explanation]

Possible Solutions:

1 - Draw by Points and Calculate Border Lines.
1 Problem - Calculation of Border Lines.

2 - Start with an ellipse and let the user reshape it by moving vertices.
2 Problem - When ellipse enlarges, it creates gaps between vertices where you can't reshape.

3 - Add and Move Vertices
3 Problem - Ear Clipping Triangulation stucks at somepoint (53th line `while` loop @ http://pastebin.com/Ug337mH2, goes into infinite loop)

**After some thinking, I decided I better work on the infinite loop (in method 3) problem rather than abandoning the add and move vertex method. What causes the infinite loop in the `while` loop at 53. line (see http://pastebin.com/Ug337mH2)?

My guess: ear clipping triangulation fails to attach some vertex to any triangle and keeps retrying.**

How I can easily implement polygon drawing in my game?

Comment: Is the user going to be constrained in how they draw the polygon?  I mean will they be prevented from creating a new line that intersects an existing one?

Comment: actually it's ok for lines to intersect each other... they are going to be grouped into seperate triangles anyway. So i think it would work even if they intersect.

Comment: solution 3 works pretty well except that infinite loop problem :/ . I kinda made a "fake" fix for infinite loop 
http://pastebin.com/nw4ZAM7d 
it ignores vertices causing infinite loop.

Comment: here is my achievement with method 3 - https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/p480x480/564250_10150693729363820_662333819_9058711_2073388123_n.jpg

Comment: My only question relates to how the tessellation of a "random" set of lines into a concave polygon is inherently ambiguous, so I assumed you would prevent lines from intersecting.

Comment: it doesnt have to be concave.after some thinking, i decided i should work on that infinite loop problem because other solutions are way too complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OpenGL's tesselator:

```
  #include <gl/gl.h>
  #include <gl/glu.h>
  #include <vector>

  using namespace std;

  typedef vector< vector< GLdouble* > > contours;
  contours poly;
  //Initialize poly here

  GLUtesselator* tess = gluNewTess();
  gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_BEGIN, (void (CALLBACK*)())&BeginCallback);
  gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_VERTEX, (void (CALLBACK*)())&VertexCallback);
  gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_END, (void (CALLBACK*)())&EndCallback);
  gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_COMBINE, (void (CALLBACK*)())&CombineCallback);
  gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_ERROR, (void (CALLBACK*)())&ErrorCallback);
  gluTessNormal(tess, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gluTessProperty(tess, GLU_TESS_WINDING_RULE, GLU_TESS_WINDING_NONZERO);
  gluTessProperty(tess, GLU_TESS_BOUNDARY_ONLY, GL_FALSE); //GL_FALSE
  gluTessBeginPolygon(tess, NULL);
  for (UINT i = 0; i < poly.size(); ++i)
  {
      gluTessBeginContour(tess);
      for (UINT j = 0; j < poly[i].size(); ++j)
      {
          gluTessVertex(tess, poly[i][j], poly[i][j]);
      }
      gluTessEndContour(tess);
  }
  gluTessEndPolygon(tess);
  gluDeleteTess(tess); // Delete after tessellation
```

Comment: im using libgdx, so glu is quite of reach here.if you know how tesselation and triangulation works can you please tell me what might be causing earclippingtriangulator class to go infinite looping. Are there any rules on vertex parameters for triangulation?

Comment: @Ahmet: That's not glut, that's glu. Different things :)

Comment: seems we have glu in libgdx lemme try ;)

Comment: glu in libgdx has only these functions (lookat , ortho2d , perspective , project , unproject ) :/

Comment: I think you're right, I can't see any reference to tesselation in libgdx. Sorry to get your hopes up / mislead you.

Comment: You could download Mesa3D source code and see how the tessellation works.